# DIVS on top of each other. Is it possible to do what appears on the image using only CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve. It's possible using CSS only or images must be used ?

[image: This is what]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to support old browsers or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sdleihssirhc's answer is great if you want to use a fieldset, if you want to keep it to divs play around with this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qT3Hz/1/

Here I'm using position relative and placing it in the center of the other div and moving it up outside the container.

Note: this is using css3 rounded corners, so browsers without css3 support will see square corners.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on it:

http://jsfiddle.net/U69Fv/

```
<fieldset class="content">
    <legend class="title">Lorem Ipsum</legend> 
</fieldset>

.title{
    margin:0 auto -1.25em;
    padding:.25em;
    width:25%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    border: 5px solid #ffce96;
    border-radius:8px; 
}

.content{
    margin:0 1em;
    padding:4em;
    background-color:#efdefe;
    border: 5px solid #ffce96;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```

*Edit: Damn, always too slow with my stuff. Oh well, plenty of options to pick from now.*

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a simple proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/Au867/) that uses border-radius with a `<legend>`:

[image: how it looks in Chrome]

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>hello, world</legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS:

```
fieldset {
    background:#eee;
    border:3px solid #ffd099;
    border-radius:10px;
    height:3em
}

legend {
    background:white;
    font:.75em/1.75 "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:3px solid #ffd099;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:10em;
    text-align:center
}
```

Depending on which browsers you're trying to support, the answer is

## Yes, it is possible with just CSS.

...or were you trying to keep it to just `<div>` elements?

Comment: great solution, I had completely forgotten about fieldset's and legend's sometimes special features :). Tnx for reminding, vote up!

Comment: No, I believe I can use other elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "position:relative" and move the element using "top, right, left or bottom" can you post the code?